# My running c++ background

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I've re installed my dev c++ and now I have problem that when I run the application of this simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<"hi mateen";
    return 0;
}
```

it shows me this:
[image]

How can I delete this? It wasn't showing before always used to use

```
getche()
```

but even when I use

```
return 0;
```

the problem is still the same.

thanks

Comment: This is not a problem. Dev C++ is that way. That line means that the code has terminated with return value 0 which means success.

Comment: This doesn't look like a problem for a development environment. Have you ttied to execute the .exe that was generated from rhe console directly ?

Comment: actually i was usig dev c++ before and this wasnt showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off "Pause console programs after return" option in "Tools > Environment Options..."

[image: Environment Options]